# Having issues saving data from multiple text fields in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c

*I'm new to Xcode so I apologise for any obvious mistakes.*

I'm building a simple app that includes the saving of data from several text fields using NSUserDefaults and populating them into a table view.

The first text field (tField) saves just fine (also used to populate the table view which works fine as well). I tried to include a second one (tField2) and it's not saving the data into the correct place when entered, right now the code actually saves the data from the first field into the second field and deletes whatever was entered into the second one.

Here's some code, I thought it best to risk including too much rather than too little.  I'll give any further info if needed, thanks very much!

### Appdelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "Data.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [Data getAllNotes];
    return YES;
}
```

### Masterview.m

```
#import "MasterViewController.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"
#import "Data.h"

@interface MasterViewController () {
    NSMutableArray *_objects;
}
@end

@implementation MasterViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                  initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self
                                  action:@selector(insertNewObject:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    ///This ensures the re-generation of list items in Table View after new saves or edits.
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self makeObjects];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

-(void)makeObjects
{
    ///This ensures list is generated in order of creation date & time.
    _objects = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[Data getAllNotes] allKeys]];
    [_objects sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
        return [(NSDate *)obj2 compare:(NSDate *)obj1];
    }];
}

- (void)insertNewObject:(id)sender
{
    [self makeObjects];
    NSString *key = [[NSDate date] description];
    [Data setNote:kDefaultText forKey:key];
    [Data setCurrentKey:key];
    [_objects insertObject:key atIndex:0];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]
                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    ///Enables transition to Detail View when New Object is created.
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:kDetailView sender:self];
}

#pragma mark - Table View

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return _objects.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"
                                                            forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSDate *object = _objects[indexPath.row];
    ///This determines which data is used to generate cell title in Table View.
    cell.textLabel.text = [[Data getAllNotes] objectForKey:[object description]];
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:
(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        ///This controls Editing Style of how Notes are deleted.
        [Data removeNoteForKey:[_objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        [Data saveNotes];
        [_objects removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]
                         withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    } else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add
        a new row to the table view.
    }
}
```

### Detailview.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) id detailItem;
///This links UI elements to code.
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *tField;
///Edited from original to include price field.
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *tField2;

@end
```

### Detailview.m

```
@synthesize tField;
///Edited from original to include price field.
@synthesize tField2;

#pragma mark - Managing the detail item

- (void)setDetailItem:(id)newDetailItem
{
    if (_detailItem != newDetailItem) {
        _detailItem = newDetailItem;
        [Data setCurrentKey:_detailItem];
        // Update the view.
        [self configureView];
    }
}

- (void)configureView
{
    NSString *currentNote = [[Data getAllNotes] objectForKey:[Data getCurrentKey]];
    if (![currentNote isEqualToString:kDefaultText]) {
        self.tField.text = currentNote;
    }
    else {
        self.tField.text = @"";
    }

    ///Edited from original. (Result: saves data from field1 in field2)

    NSString *currentNote2 = [[Data getAllNotes] objectForKey:[Data getCurrentKey]];
    if (![currentNote2 isEqualToString:kDefaultText]) {
        self.tField2.text = currentNote2;
    }
    else {
        self.tField2.text = @"";
    }

    ///This is what initalizes keyboard upon entry.
    [self.tField becomeFirstResponder];
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    if (![self.tField.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
        [Data setNoteForCurrentKey:self.tField.text];
    }
    else {
        [Data removeNoteForKey:[Data getCurrentKey]];
    }
    [Data saveNotes];
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your viewWillAppear only saves the data from the first one.

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    if (![self.tField.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
        //SET THE CURRENT KEY HERE
        [Data setNoteForCurrentKey:self.tField.text];
    }
    else {
        //SET THE CURRENT KEY HERE
        [Data removeNoteForKey:[Data getCurrentKey]];
    }

    if (![self.tField2.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
        //SET THE CURRENT KEY HERE
        [Data setNoteForCurrentKey:self.tField2.text];
    }
    else {
        //SET THE CURRENT KEY HERE
        [Data removeNoteForKey:[Data getCurrentKey]];
    }
    [Data saveNotes];

}
```

There is also the issue of your only having one detail item. This means that you only have a pointer to the second item (it will remain your currentNote. In order to fix this, you need to have two detailItem properties (one for the first note and one for the second. Then, when you save the notes, set the proper one to become active.

Comment: You really must call `[super viewWillDisappear:animated];`.

Comment: That too, I missed that the first time. I will add it

Comment: Thanks very much for your response, that makes complete sense. What code should I use to set the current key? I'm guessing that setting the current key for each instance is how you call upon the different detailitem properties.