# Looking for code to 'set current key' when saving data --iOS App--

Tags: ios, objective-c

I recently posted a question regarding some issues I'm having saving data into text fields for an app I'm building in Xcode.  The question can be seen here,

[Having issues saving data from multiple text fields in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21767688/having-issues-saving-data-from-multiple-text-fields-in-xcode)

I received a very helpful answer which helped clue me in to exactly where I was going wrong, but I'm still unsure about the code needed to set the current key when specifying which field to save data from.

Here is the code:

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewWillDisappear:animated];
if (![self.tField.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
    //SET THE CURRENT KEY HERE
    [Data setNoteForCurrentKey:self.tField.text];
}
else {
    //SET THE CURRENT KEY HERE
    [Data removeNoteForKey:[Data getCurrentKey]];
}

if (![self.tField2.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
    //SET THE CURRENT KEY HERE
    [Data setNoteForCurrentKey:self.tField2.text];
}
else {
    //SET THE CURRENT KEY HERE
    [Data removeNoteForKey:[Data getCurrentKey]];
}
[Data saveNotes];

}
```

I added a second detail item property to enable the second text field to be saved, but don't know what code to use to call upon the different detail items.  Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: ? You mean how to know which item `setNoteForCurrentKey:` should operate on?

Comment: Yeah, basically just being able to save the 2 different textfields, (tfield1&2 in the code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setNoteForCurrentKey:` should take two parameters, not one. Then you can pass the key and the value associated with it. Something like:

```
- (void)setNote:(NSString *)note forKey:(NSString *)key
```

Using a 'current key' just makes maintenance of that information an issue that you don't need.

In your current code, because you have 2 `if` statements, you can set the keys as literal values in the code. That isn't very scalable, so going forwards you might want to think about storing your text fields in an array and having another array with the corresponding key names.